# How to add an input label for select html tag

Tags: html, css

I want to add header text "Selected subscriptions" on my select html tag.
[image]

```html
 <div>
  <select name="select"> 
    <option value="value1" selected>Subscription 1</option>
    <option value="value2">Subscription 2</option>
    <option value="value3">Subscription 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you looking for [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) ? ([MDN : select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select))

Answer (score 2):

This is called a [Input Label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) in HTML. There are two options to link a label and a form field:

**1. Use `for` and `id` attributes on label and field respectively**

```
<label for="subscription-select">Selected subscriptions</label>
<select id="subscription-select" name="select">
    <option value="1">Sub 1</option>
</select>
```

**2. Nest form field inside label**

```
<label>
    Selected subscriptions
    <select id="subscription-select" name="select">
        <option value="1">Sub 1</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

Comment: I need this label to be inside  input

Comment: Then use option 2 and style it accordingly. You can use `pointer-events: none` on the label so the click goes through to the `select`. Feel free to edit your question or open a new one if you run into trouble with the CSS.